Upload the excel file (.xlsx) on BIM360
After upload the file on BIM360 when i try to open file on BIM360 and download on local machine its occure same error like "This workbook couldn't be opened because the file format may not be matching with the file extension" but when i upload driect from BIM360 Account it is working fine(its open bith place well).
It should be open on while I am downloading oe open on BIM360

Are you saying you get the error when upload the .xlsx file with Data Management API, but works Ok by UI? Did you follow the tutorial at https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/? Please make sure to always use the correct extension .xlsx for the file name and object key.
